# How to get the dates available in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

I am not very good with this, so I hope somebody can help me. I have a table filled with measurements. These measurements are taken every 30 seconds over the last 3 years, during most of the days. I would like to have a list with all the dates available in the table. So something like:

```
31//1/2010
1/2/2010
2/2/2010
4/2/2010
```

It does not matter how many measurements were taken on a certain day, as long as there is one then it should show the date. In the above example it shows that there are no measurements taken on 3/2/2010.

Is there a simple mysql select statement that can do this?

my table looks like this:

table1:

```
int id (auto, prim)
datetime measurementTime
double value1
double value2
```

Comment: please the Tabel description (which field type was used for date) and some sample rows. On first glance, either DISTINCT or GROUP BY could help, but that depends on the data type fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(`column_with_date_and_time`) AS `date` 
       FROM `table` ORDER BY `date`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_col FROM your_table
```

if your table stores date and time separately.
On the contrary, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date_time_col) FROM your_table
```